# How to find midpoint of an Arc on a 3D Plane

Tags: 3d

I'm not sure if this is even possible but here it goes:

Let's assume we have a 3D Circle with 2 points on it
A (1, 5, 2) B (5, 2, 1), and the circle's center O (0, 0, 0)

Is it possible to find C based on the conditions that the distance from C to the center is the radius and distances from C to A and B are equal?

Comment: Huh?  There is an infinite number of circles that will go through two points.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Center is $(0,0,0)$

Comment: I just added having a center O (0, 0, 0) which means that in this example the distance of A and B to O is 5.47, which means C should have the same distance, isn't there a way to find C?

Comment: @MarioAda there'll be 2 such $C$'s, one along the minor arc and one along the major

Comment: @Jamāl I'm trying to find the one on the minor arc

Comment: @MarioAda I guess you could formulate equations based on the conditions that distance from $C$ to center is the radius and distances from $C$ to $A$ and $B$ are equal

Comment: @Jamāl that is correct but I'm not sure how to do that, I'm currently looking into Inscribed Angles hoping that would somehow help

Comment: Can you use cross product?

Comment: @Andrei I guess I need to find the distance between C and AB first, cross product would be helpful then, I'm gonna try that right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way in my view would be to take the midpoint of $AB$ and scale it to a point on the sphere (ie, a point whose distance from $O$ is the radius).

Comment: I like your solution better than mine :)

Comment: $$r {\rm norm} \left(\frac{{\bf A} + {\bf B}}{2} \right)$$.  The circle's radius $r$ times the normalized mean of the known points.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that right away!

Answer (score 0):

You know that point $C$ is between $A$ and $B$, in the $AOB$ plane. Using $C=(x,y,z)$ you know that $$\vec{AO}\times\vec{CO}=\vec{CO}\times\vec{BO}$$
This accounts both for the fact that $C$ is in the $AOB$ plane, and also that the angle is the same. It yields a system with three unknown and three equations, but only two are independent. You can get the last one by using $|AO|=|CO|$, or $$x^2+y^2+z^2=1^2+5^2+2^2$$

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that right away too!